# Rails generate html file from html.erb template

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rendering

I know thas it sounds a little weird. I need to generate an html file based on an html.erb template which has many variables. I will give an oversimplified example.

In my viwes/pages/home.html.erb I have:

```
<html>
     <h1> <%= @name %> </h1>
</html>
```

In my pages_controller.rb:

```
def home
   @name = 'Michaela'
end
```

When the home funcion is called, it will render the home.html.erb and in the browser, the content will be showed as if it was opnening an .html file that looks like the following:

```
<html>
    <h1> Michaela </h1>
</html>
```

What I need is to generate an plain html file with that content, after @name has been defined, so if instad of being hardcoded, it´s inputted by the user, the .html file defines it´s content accroding to that user input.

Comment: You can do like this : https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/how-render-to-file/210829/2 or either render a template to a string. The whole page basically will become a string that can write to a file. `ActionController::Base.renderer.render_to_string(template: "pages/home", locals: {:@name=> @name})`

Comment: Thanks! Didn´t know about the render_to_String helper, but was what I nedded!

Answer (score 0):

As Maxence recommended, I used the render_to_string helper to finally store the generated html into a variable, and manipulate it in that way.